# How to correctly use while and if statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to practice on my while statements and if statement, can someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong? I will be providing the code which matches my own just with out my examples of zip-codes and the where the polling stations are:

```
print ("VOTER ELIGIBILITY AND POLLING STATION PROGRAM\n")
ageMin = 18
end = 0
zipCode = 0
usrAge = int(input("\nEnter your age (Type '0' to exit program): "))
while usrAge < ageMin and usrAge != end:
    print("YOU ARE INELIGIBLE TO VOTE")
    usrAge = int(input("\nEnter your age (Type '0' to exit program): "))
if usrAge == end:
    input("\nRun complete. Press the Enter key to exit.")
while usrAge != end:
    zipCode = int(input("\nEnter your residence's zip code: "))
    usrAge = int(input("\nEnter your age (Type '0' to exit program): "))
    input("\nRun complete. Press the Enter key to exit.")
if zipCode == "93620":
    print("Your polling station is 123 elm st.")
    if zipCode == "83340":
        print("Your polling station is 14 bell monte st. ")
    elif zipCode == "76324":
        print("Your polling station is  147 avalon dr.")
    elif zipCode == "15547":
        print("Your polling station is 632 elena st. ")
    elif zipCode == "63295":
        print("Your polling station is 100 monte clare st.")
    else:
        print("Error – unknown zip code")
```

The script runs but for some reason it does not display the correct polling address, it just goes directly to the else statement even when I don't want it to, and i was also attempting to loop the usrAge statement, so that the user can the prompt when ever they would like.

Example:

```
VOTER ELIGIBILITY AND POLLING STATION PROGRAM


Enter your age (Type '0' to exit program): 19

Enter your residence's zip code: myzipCode

Enter your age (Type '0' to exit program): 0

Run complete. Press the Enter key to exit.
Error – unknown zip code
```

Comment: I think you might have some copy-paste errors, at least in the code you've provided here: the last two `if`s and the following `elif`s are exactly alike(?).

Comment: yes they are alike because on my end i have different zip codes in place as well as polling station addresses

Comment: `myzipCode` is not valid input for this program. What are you typing there?

Comment: @LeoV. Are you sure you've indented your code correctly? As it is presented here now, it will stop and evaluate `if zipCode == "93620"`. If `False`, then exit.

Comment: @LeoV. If my answer below solved your issue, please mark it as "accepted". Or, if you've implemented your own solution, please post it below and accept that.

Answer (score 0):

First, check your indention. The code you've presented here seems to have some indention issues.

Then, the error here is most likely that you input the zip code as a number (you've incapsulated your `input` with an `int()`), but compares as if the zip code was a string: `"123" == 123` will evaluate to `False`!

Either remove `"` in your `zipCode == "76324"`, or change to `str(zipCode) == "76324"`.

*EDIT - A pythonic tip:*
I get that you're testing out `if`s and `while`s, but for the future, a more *pythonic* approach could be to use a dictionary, like this

```
zipcodes = {93620:"123 elm st", 83340:"14 bell monte st"}

zipCode = 93620
if int(zipCode) in zipcodes:
    print("Your polling station is ", zipcodes[zipCode])
else:
    print("ERROR - unknown zip code: '%s'" % zipCode)
```